# android sdk - cannot import any java.* classes

Tags: java, android

I am unable to import any java classes in my android app. I can access any android.* imports but when i compile importing java.net or any other java ns i get error: cannot find symbol. baffled

Comment: which class you exactly trying to import which is showing the compile time error

Comment: i am trying to import java.net. i am using 'ant debug' to build and the compile time error is 'error: cannot find symbol' and then a pointer to the line on which i declare import of java.net

Comment: please post the exact import statement

Comment: ok the error is because i am not providing a class after 'net'. silly mistake. is should reference a class to import or import all of them either like this 'import java.net.Socket;' or this 'import java.net.*'

Comment: I get "Only a type can be imported. java.net resolves to a package" when trying to import just "java.net". You should perhaps specify what you want to import from the java.net package?

Answer (score 2):

> <strike>LOL here</strike>, import java.net;

`import java.net;`

Is **not** a valid statement.

It should end with class / wild card * or static field you can say `import com.abc`